# Eclipse PDT - Lost content assist. OverlappingFileLockException

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I used Eclipse PDT Mars on 2010 Macbook for years - no problem.

I got a 2013 Macbook with latest OS. Transferred everything with migration assistant.

After OS update, I updated Eclipse - because Mars crashed every time I pressed delete with highlighted text on new OS.

I used default startup options for Eclipse 2020.

Sadly - no PHP content assist after update to Eclipse 2020 - "No default proposals."

Errors:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface.text 4 0 2020-04-11 00:12:22.371
!MESSAGE Unexpected runtime error while computing a text hover
!STACK 0
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
```

Note: `OverlappingFileLockException` is repeated many times in log files.

How can I get my content assist to work? I tried changing settings, deleting work spaces.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess, Eclipse Mars is too old to update (AFAIK on macOS the file structure changed). Please try to install the Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers from scratch. If the issue remains, show the full log (after deleting the log and reproducing the issue).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @howlger

I reinstalled and created new workspace.

PHP content assist worked - and log has no errors - after I put empty workspace on main disk instead of external flash drive.

I think MacOS Catalina added too much security for external drives.